# Using setuptools in your package's setup.py -- How do you conditionally install a script?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

How do you configure your setup.py so that it does not attempt to overwrite a script if it already exists?  Or at least finish the rest of the package installation if writing a script fails.  I am using setuptools for [my setup.py](https://github.com/CleanCut/green/blob/b617e8ec2687b22201498a5f9d53fab1d3475a6c/setup.py).  The relevant part of setup.py is this:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts' : [
        'green = green:main',  # <-- The one I have problems with
        'green%d = green:main' % sys.version_info[:1],     # green2 or green3
        'green-%d.%d = green:main' % sys.version_info[:2], # green-3.4 etc.
        ],
},
```

[my setup.py](https://github.com/CleanCut/green/blob/b617e8ec2687b22201498a5f9d53fab1d3475a6c/setup.py) has both versioned scripts (the version of python is included in the name of the script) and unversioned scripts.  On OS X I use system python for 2.7, which requires superuser permissions to run pip (sudo pip ...), which causes the script to get installed under `/usr/local/bin` with root ownership.  Then when I try installing under python 3.4 installed via homebrew with user permissions, it attempts (and fails) to overwrite the unversioned script in `/usr/local/bin`.  I don't mind that it can't overwrite the script file, I do mind that pip fails the install and leaves the half-installed package in a weird, funky state.

I would like to be able to instruct setup.py to either not attempt to install a script if it was already installed by something else, or at least to ignore the error and continue with the rest of the installation if it doesn't have permissions to overwrite the script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware, if standard `setup` function behaviour support your requirement.

But I am sure, following can be done:

## Ask `setup` only for what is really possible

1. before you call your `setup`, check, if the script is already present and you are willing to reinstall it or skip. You are in Python script, so you have full Python power at hand, use it to investigate the situation and make the decision.
2. When calling `setup`, construct the value of `entry_points` in such a way, it does what you need (either install or not install the script).

Anyway, this has the dificulty, you need to do your own analysis, if the script to install is already there, where it is, check, if you shall update it or not etc.

## Try asking `setup` for what you want, if it fails, ask for less

As `setup` is a funcion, you can put it into `try` and `except`, if you know, that you can resolve the problem asking to install without first script, second try may go this way.

Comment: So, for that to work in a cross-platform way, I would need to be able to make a call to setuptools to find out where the script would be installed on this system (not the same path on all systems).  Any idea where I could find that path?  I searched for setuptools API docs, and all I found was [this useless section](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#reusing-setuptools-code) and [the pkg_resources documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#api-reference)  that looked promising, but I didn't find it in there anywhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Nathan No idea, where it goes installed. I would either dive into setuptools code to check this, or use try - except around `setup` call. But these days I have no time to test deeper.